# condition on populate not working : node mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tried to fetch district data based dcCoordinator.academicYear and dcCoordinator.userId, however it is giving all data instead of and filter.

Please find the code below

```
const districtSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    county: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'County',
      required: true
    },
    academicYear: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'AcademicYear',
        required: true
    }],
    dcCoordinator: {
      type: [{
        academicYear: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'AcademicYear',
          required: true
        },
        userId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
          required: true
        }
      }],
      required: false
    }
  });
  
  module.exports = mongoose.model('District', districtSchema, "district");
```

Query is

```
let districtnew = await District.findOne({
            _id: districtId,
            'dcCoordinator.academicYear': academicYearId,
            'dcCoordinator.userId': oldUserId,
        })
```

Comment: something like [this?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q4WiMaKgj5q)

Comment: Tried above solutions still getting all data

Comment: maybe you can create an example playground or give example input/output

Comment: How can findOne() give all data ?